# How to execute a command CREATE USER from mysql inside Spring Project?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have a Spring project and when i create a register user on table i have to create a database user too.

Now i have:

```
user = userRepository.save(user);
```

The command is:

```
CREATE USER 'username' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
//UserService

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

...
user = userRepository.save(user);
jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE USER \'username\' IDENTIFIED BY \'password\'");
```

Note that your datasource user defined in application properties should have suitable privileges to create user and etc.